# tinymce, configuring built in button icons

Tags: tinymce-4

Is it possible to configure the toolbar buttons `styleselect` and `fontsizeselect`
to use custom icons rather than the default text they have? and if so how. all the examples I've come across so far involve defining your own custom button to add on, which seems like a lot just to replace some text with an icon.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One way you can change these is to use a language file for `en_US` and put replacements there.  To make this work you need to do 2 things:

**1 - Add a language configuration option to your init:**

```
tinymce.init({ 
  selector: '#myTextArea',
  language: 'en_US',   //Force custom translations of button/menu text in English.
  ...
});
```

**2 - Add a `en_US.js` file to your `langs` folder within TinyMCE.**
This file is where TinyMCE looks for language translations so if you tell TinyMCE explicitly to use the `en_US` language it will look in the `langs` folder for a JS file of the same name as the language.  You can then put updated translations in that file:

```
tinymce.addI18n('en_US',{
  "Formats": "Custom Formats Text",
  "Font Sizes": "Custom Font Size Text"
});
```

To see all your options for what you can change just grab a language file from here:  https://www.tinymce.com/download/language-packages/  The label on the left is the "key" and the value on the right is the "value".  The "key" is effectively what you get in English when you don't include a reference to a language in the `tinymce.init({})` call..